# how to access asp.net controls inside <td> of table using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, repeater

I have a asp.net page as

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">

<%--<div class="tab-content">--%>
<%-- <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">--%>

    <div class="container" id="div_frm">

        <form id="frmQuestion">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-body" style="max-height: 400;overflow-y: scroll;">
              <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptmgr" runat="server"> </asp:ScriptManager>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptQuestions" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <table class="table" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="10px" border="solid" id="tableQuestion">
                            <tr style="color:Black; background-color:Teal; border:solid;">
                                <th style="width:20px">No.</th>
                                <th style="width:100px">Question</th>
                                <th style="width:40px">QuestionType</th>
                                <th style="width:110px">Text Answer</th>
                                <th style="width:100px">Multiple Choice 1</th>
                                <th style="width:100px">Multiple Choice 2</th>
                                <th style="width:100px">Multiple Choice 3</th>
                                <th style="width:100px">Multiple Choice 4</th>
                                <th style="width:70px">True/False</th>
                                <th>Controls</th>
                            </tr>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr style="color:Black; background-color:Silver; border:solid;" id="trdata" class="trclass">

                            <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNo" Text='<%#Eval("Qno") %>' /></td>

                            <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQuestion" Text='<%#Eval("Question") %>'></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtQuestion" Text='<%#Eval("Question") %>'  Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQid" Text='<%#Eval("Qid") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label></td>

                            <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQtype" Text='<%#Eval("Qtype") %>' ></asp:Label>
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlQType" Visible="false"></asp:DropDownList>
                           <%-- <select class="dropdown" id="ddlQType" name="ddlQType" style="width:100px" runat="server">
                                        <option value="0">--Select--</option>
                                        <option value="1">Descriptive Answer</option>
                                        <option value="2">Multiple Choice </option>
                                        <option value="3">True/False answer</option></select>--%></td>

                            <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAnsDesc" Text='<%#Eval("description") %>' Width="100px" ></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAnsDesc" Text='<%#Eval("description") %>' Width="100px" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox></td>

                            <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblch1" Text='<%#Eval("choice1") %>' Width="100px" ></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtch1" Text='<%#Eval("choice1") %>' Width="100px" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox></td>

                            <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblch2" Text='<%#Eval("choice2") %>' Width="100px" ></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtch2" Text='<%#Eval("choice2") %>' Width="100px" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox></td>

                            <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblch3" Text='<%#Eval("choice3") %>' Width="100px" ></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtch3" Text='<%#Eval("choice3") %>' Width="100px" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox></td>

                            <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblch4" Text='<%#Eval("choice4") %>' Width="100px" ></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtch4" Text='<%#Eval("choice4") %>' Width="100px" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox></td>

                            <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblisTrue" Text='<%# Eval("isTrue") %>' Width="70px" ></asp:Label>
                            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkistrue" Checked='<%#(Eval("isTrue")=="true") %>' Width="70px" Visible="false"/></td>

                            <td> <span class="more"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" Text="Edit" runat="server" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" OnClientClick="getdata();" CausesValidation="false" />
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" Text="Update" runat="server" Visible="false" OnClick="OnUpdate" CausesValidation="false" />
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" Visible="false" OnClick="OnCancel" CausesValidation="false" />
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" Text="Delete" runat="server" OnClick="OnDelete" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to delete this row?');" />
                            </span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </table>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
                </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>

            </div>
            </div>


             <!-- Modal example -->

 <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->

 <p class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="btnshowmodal" runat="server">Edit</button> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</p>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center">RESULT</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQuestionNumber" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtQuestionDesc" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQuestionType" Text="Select Type :"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <select class="dropdown" id="ddlQType" name="ddlQType" onchange="ShowHide();return false;" style="width:310px" >
                        <option value="0">--Select--</option>
                        <option value="1">Descriptive Answer</option>
                        <option value="2">Multiple Choice </option>
                        <option value="3">True/False answer</option></select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text="Answer :"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <textarea runat="server" id="textareaQuestion" rows="2" cols="40"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label2" Text="True/False :"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbtrue" Text=" True " GroupName="tf" />
                <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbfalse" Text=" False " GroupName="tf" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMultiAns1" Text="Enter first Choice :"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMulti1" runat="server" Width="310px"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:CheckBox class="checkbox" runat="server" ID="chkmulti1" Text="Tick if answer is correct." />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMultiAns2" Text="Enter Second Choice :"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMulti2" runat="server" Width="310px"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:CheckBox class="checkbox" runat="server" ID="chkmulti2" Text="Tick if answer is correct." />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMultiAns3" Text="Enter Third Choice :"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMulti3" runat="server" Width="310px"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:CheckBox class="checkbox" runat="server" ID="chkmulti3" Text="Tick if answer is correct." />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMultiAns4" Text="Enter Fourth Choice :"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMulti4" runat="server" Width="310px"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:CheckBox class="checkbox" runat="server" ID="chkmulti4" Text="Tick if answer is correct." />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <asp:Button class="btn" runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
                <asp:Button class="btn" runat="server" ID="Button2" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false"
                        onclick="btnCancel_Click" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>

         </div>
        </div>


            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
            </div>
      </div>

        </form>
    </div>
```

when i click on edit link button in repeater a modal popup opens with empty fields but i want to get the values of that corresponding row
I tried row click event as

```
$(function () {
      $(".trclass").click(function () {
          var quest = $(this).closest('[id*="lblQuestion"]').text();
          alert(quest);
      });
  });
```

to check if I can access these values but failed.
So how can i access these values and insert into the modal?
Or do i need to change the design?

Comment: `$(this).find('[id*="lblQuestion"]')`

Answer (score 0):

The closest() method returns the first ancestor of the selected element. An ancestor is a parent, grandparent, great-grandparent, and so on so it will not work , what you need is find method as

```
var quest = $(this).find('[id*="lblQuestion"]').text();
```

The find() method returns descendant elements of the selected element.

Comment: Thanks Rahul find method worked like a miracle. But I cannot get how to insert values into controls inside myModal. I tried the code $("#txtboxid").val(quest); but it does not display inside the textbox inside modal. Can you tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: What you are doing is assigning values to modal when it is not even created in DOM, you need to assign the values on modal function